# Brake Pedal doesn't Return after Replacing Brake Booster

Tags: brakes, nissan, sentra, brake-booster

I finally got around to [replacing the brake booster](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/83376/7132) on my 99 Nissan Sentra / Almera n15.

So I removed the master cylinder, replaced the booster, hooked everything back up and started the process of bleeding the brakes.  Low and behold, I press the brake pedal down and it won't return.  I tested the booster before installation, it holds vacuum and pressing in the clevis releases the vacuum completely.  Before starting the bleed, I topped up the fluid.

Is there actually a problem here, or is this just because there's air in the brake system and once it's completely bled it'll start working OK?

Just to emphasize, the brakes worked before replacing the booster - i.e. I disconnected the vacuum hose from the booster and plugged it and was able to use the brakes even though I had to press pretty hard and it would return after each press.

**EDIT Aug. 19th, 2022**

So I replaced the master cylinder and now the breaks just go all the way to the floor.  I have a mittyvac, and am having trouble bleeding the breaks, I can hardly get any fluid through the lines.  I prefilled the cylinder, and think I got all the air out of it, so I'm not sure where to look at this point.

EDIT Aug. 24, 2022

Bled every drop of air out of the system, breaks work, but pedal doesn't return.  If I disconnect the vacuum hose to the booster the breaks release, or I can also toe them up.  So only thing I can think of is I was unlucky and got a bad booster from the junk yard.

Comment: I'm going to ask the "stupid" question of you ... did you replace the actuator rod from the brake pedal back into the new booster?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 When you say actuator rod, you mean the rod that comes out the back of the booster and connects to the brake pedal?  Yes, I did connect that.

Comment: That is the one ... depending on the vehicle, it can go either way :o) Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So any ideas?  Think doing a full bleed of the system will solve the problem?

Comment: I think the best you can try is to just see if you can pull the pedal back and pump it again and see if it comes back. If it will gain any pressure, keep doing it until it pumps all the way up. You may try this with the engine running, so the booster can be drawn down on vacuum and help assist. Best I can give you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I completely bled the brakes, and same problem.  Prior to replacing the booster, I would have to disconnect the vacuum hose to get brakes to release, but now with the "new" junkyard booster the brakes stay engaged,  but I can toe up the pedal to release them...  I'm wondering if there is some problem with this booster I got from the junkyard...

Comment: That would be my next guess ... if the brakes themselves are working (calipers), there's very little left it could be (booster or master). Sometimes the junkyard parts bite us ... though I bet you could take it back and get a replacement fairly easy.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  So I replaced the master cylinder and still having problems, see my edit...

Comment: Is the brake booster's push rod protrusion length adjusted to match the depth into the master cylinder? https://youtu.be/rYYzPIGoxfY

Comment: @adatum yeah, it's off an identical vehicle and had the same depth as the one I took off my car.